# Finding the 8 outer corner vertices of an object

Tags: python

What might be the best or easiest way to find the 8 corner vertices of an object (usually cube in shape with more vertices than 8) and then selecting them.

Example Image:
[image]

I am starting off this code with just selecting the top 4 but receiving an error when I add:

```
from bmesh import from_edit_mesh
import bpy

def select4vertTop():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')        
    bmT = from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
    i=0   
    a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=vPrev=vSelCoord[0] #hold first vert coords to compare with next
    print()
    print( 'vPrev %f %f %f\n' % (vPrev.x, vPrev.y, vPrev.z) )    
    for vert in bmT.verts:        
        print( 'v%i %f %f %f\n' % (i, vert.co.x, vert.co.y, vert.co.z) )
        if  vert.co.x >= a.x and \
            vert.co.y >= a.y and \
            vert.co.z >= a.z:
                a=vert
        if  vert.co.x >= b.x and \
            vert.co.y >= b.y and \
            vert.co.z <= b.z:
                b=vert
        if  vert.co.x >= c.x and \
            vert.co.y <= c.y and \
            vert.co.z >= c.z:
                c=vert
        if  vert.co.x >= d.x and \
            vert.co.y <= d.y and \
            vert.co.z <= d.z:
                d=vert
        if  vert.co.x <= e.x and \
            vert.co.y <= e.y and \
            vert.co.z <= e.z:
                e=vert
        if  vert.co.x <= f.x and \
            vert.co.y >= f.y and \
            vert.co.z >= f.z:
                f=vert
        if  vert.co.x <= g.x and \
            vert.co.y >= g.y and \
            vert.co.z <= g.z:
                g=vert
        if  vert.co.x <= h.x and \
            vert.co.y <= h.y and \
            vert.co.z >= h.z:
                h=vert
        i+=1
        #a,c,f,h are the top vertices
 
    print("a%i,c%i,f%i,h%i" % (ai,ci,fi,hi))
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
 
    obj.data.vertices[ai].select = True
    obj.data.vertices[ci].select = True    
    obj.data.vertices[fi].select = True
    obj.data.vertices[hi].select = True       
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    select4vertTop()
```

I apologize I rarely use python.

Comment: How do you define the **outer**?

Comment: @HikariTW, I've attached a sample screenshot.

Comment: If the center of the mesh is also center of the cube (origin is the mass center). And there is no other noisy vertices around corner. You can determine it by the distance to origin. which is the sum of the three axes square value. Sort them in order and retrieve the first 8 vertices.

Comment: @HikariTW, that actually makes sense. Most of the time the origin will be the center of the cube and there won't be other noisy vertices around the corners.Now I have to figure out how to do that in python. I guess it's not simple to do what you said in python :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`KDTree` and the objects bounding box.**

Each object has an axis aligned bounding box giving the 8 coordinates of the cuboid the object fits into. If a cuboid is perfectly axis aligned the bounding box corner coordinates exactly match those of the corner verts.

A [`KDTree`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.kdtree.html) can be used to quickly find the closest element to a coordinate

Putting it together in a script, run with object of interest in edit mode (vertex select mode)

*Note, this method assumes the mesh is axis aligned*

[image]
*Result of running on default UV sphere*

```
import bmesh
from mathutils.kdtree import KDTree
from bpy import context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

kd = KDTree(len(bm.verts))

for v in bm.verts:
    kd.insert(v.co, v.index)

kd.balance()

# get closest to 8 bbox corners

closest = [kd.find(tuple(c))[1] for c in ob.bound_box]
print(closest)
#select 

for v in bm.verts:
    v.select = v.index in closest

bm.select_flush_mode()    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

**Ordering the result**

The bounding box is "wound" in a consistent order. Looking at the default cube

```
>>> bbox = [tuple(b) for b in C.object.bound_box]
>>> for i, v in enumerate(bbox):
...     i, v
...     
(0, (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0))
(1, (-1.0, -1.0, 1.0))
(2, (-1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
(3, (-1.0, 1.0, -1.0))
(4, (1.0, -1.0, -1.0))
(5, (1.0, -1.0, 1.0))
(6, (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
(7, (1.0, 1.0, -1.0))
```

Hence the front `y=-1`, top (`z=1`) , left (`x=1`) vert is index 5. The 4 verts that make up the top corners are at indices `1, 2, 5, 6`
The `closest` list has the same order.

**If a definite 8 corner cuboid**

In a cuboid mesh the 8 corner verts are only linked to 3 edges, whereas all others are linked to 4.  Can use this.

```
import bmesh
from bpy import context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for v in bm.verts:
    v.select = (
            len(v.link_edges) == 3
            )

bm.select_flush_mode()    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

If this is also axis aligned then the "order" could be determined by looking at the components of the vertex normals.  *For example, the normals of the corner verts of default cube would be equivalent to their normalized coordinates*

Comment: What if the cube is rotated in edit mode?

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER, that seems to be for the most part what I might need. I ran a couple tests so far. Not sure if I'll be having any objects rotated in edit mode but I'll have to watch out for that and consider that if it happens.

Comment: Part 1 answered but I didn't mention that I wanted to extend on this, how would I get the "coordinates" of a single side using your answer to the next step like I tried to find the top 4 in my original post.

Comment: In bbox method bbox has a consistent order `[tuple(b) for b in C.object.bound_box]` in python console on default cube, all those with z = 1 are top. `closest` is in same order.  For second method could look at vertex normals. Any with an up component `v.normal.angle((0, 0, 1)) < pi / 2` will be top verts.

Answer (score 2):

The naive solution is easy enough to do in Python:
[image]

```
from bmesh import from_edit_mesh
import bpy


def select4vertTop(k: int = 8) -> None:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    mesh = from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
    # Define a helper function that we calculate distance, using Euclidean distance.
    get_distance = lambda v: v.co.x ** 2 + v.co.y ** 2 + v.co.z ** 2
    # We sorted our verts using the helper, reverse flag is set to true.
    verts = sorted(mesh.verts, reverse=True, key=get_distance)
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    # From the first k vertex, set select to True.
    for v in verts[:k]:
        v.select_set(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    select4vertTop()
```

Although non of the exception and situation is properly handled by counting on distance.
See the @batFINGER's answer for more general approach.

Comment: I might use this for another situation. The one test I ran at first is creating 2 cubes a few units away from each other then I joined them. but the result using this sample only selected the 2nd cube vertices which was further from the world origin. (Hmmm maybe because I didn't center the origin between both cubes) Maybe you need code to account for that.

Comment: You can modify the `get_distance` function to make it compare with object mass center.

Comment: I just had to add:     bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT') and bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center='MEDIAN') and I got it to work :-) Thanks

Comment: Suggest could directly use `v.co.length_squared` or `v.co.length`